# Unable to call local server-less NodeJS setup from android device

Tags: android, node.js, localhost, serverless-framework

Hi all I have a local nodejs setup and using the serverless framework. When I call the endpoint from browser of postman it works, however when I call from my android device on the same network it does not work.

This is my serverless.yml

```
service: aws-debug-locally

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    httpsProtocol: "cert"
    noPrependStageInUrl: true

functions:
  hello:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: any
```

this generates the url:
https://localhost:3000/hello

which when called from browser/ postman it works.

Then on my android dev app I have the following:

```
      axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded/json/gzip';
      axios.defaults.headers.post.Authorization = token;

      const url = 'https://localhost:3000/hello';
      return axios.post(url, compressedData, {
        onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
          console.log('uploading')
        },
        onDownloadProgress: progressEvent => {
          console.log('downloading')
        },
      }).then((response) => {
      });
```

when this runs, android studio gives the following error:

```
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 2519 - Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Network Error
    Error: Network Error



polyfills.js:3467          POST https://localhost:3000/hello net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

and the chrome inspector shows the errors in the pictures attached.

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwqCd.png)
[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRmOj.png)

Comment: Have you tried using the IP address of the nodejs server, instead of localhost?

Comment: @JuniusL. 
I have tried http://mylaptopid:3000/hello
and 
http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello 
If thats what you mean?

Comment: ```127.0.0.1``` is localhost, use the actual ip address of the machine

Comment: Its the same, I tried with http and https and just get connection refused, even from the browsers on the device

Node i am on linux machine

Comment: run ```curl ifconfig.me```.this will return your IP address

Comment: I get the same result with myip:3000/hello  of connection refused

Comment: Say "myip" refused to connect